# Adwords API Exception Throw

Tags: c#, exception, google-ads-api

I have my parent class calls a child class for a string API response. I have a try and catch block for my parent class while the child class does not have any try, catch and throw. When there is an AdwordsReportException in the child class, it is kind of captured within first line in the image i attached in the parent class. I am wondering if there is way to parse that first line in the image and drill down to the details. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are having difficulty because you are catching `Exception` rather than `ReportsException`?

You should, in general, catch the most specific Exception you anticipate so you should modify your `try{}catch{}` block to catch that specific report exception:

```
        catch (ReportsException exp)
        {

        }
```

(You could, instead, feasibly start getting the type of `exp` and casting it within the `catch` block but that's going to get ugly and messy v quickly - definately recommend just catching `ReportsException`)

Either way once you have a `ReportsException` object you can easily interrogate it for the specfic errors like so:

```
        foreach (var error in exp.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorType.ToString());
            //or do other things useful things with error
        }
```

UPDATE:

Having looked again at your screenshot it seems your exception is of type `AdWordsReportException` rather than `ReportsExcpetion` as I find. I don't think the latest version of the AdWords .net client library has this exception? Are you using an old version? No matter - either way the advice is the same and I am sure you can interrogate whichever Exception to get what you need